# notification content title is cut off

Tags: android, notifications

I understand from this [link](http://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/an-example-of-how-to-run-a-background-task-and-report-progress-in-the-status-bar-using-asynctask-on-android/) to create a notification in the android status bar. However, if my content title is too long, the word will get cut off. May i know how to enable a "bouncing" effect in the content title of the notification? I.e: if the user is in the notification drawer and the content title is too long, it will slowly scroll to the back automatically, all in 1 line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already the stock behavior for a `Notification`. The `View` that holds the `Notification` title and text implements `android:ellipsize="marquee"`, and will therefore scroll if the width of the content exceeds the width of the `View`. This effect only occurs if the Notification is focused.